# In peichart in flutter, how to add outside label in feilds?

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter peri chart, i want to add out side label and inside label simultaneosly,but  i am trying to add these things, but not getting proper, outiside label only got in one item. here i am sharing the code. Please add , i am stucking it .

```
 new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        colorFn: (sale, __) => charts.Color.fromHex(code: sale.colorCode),
        // fillColorFn: (LinearSales sales, _) =>
        //     charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xFFFFB8D8)),
        data: dataToShow,
        labelAccessorFn: (LinearSales row, _) => '${row.sales}',
      )




charts.PieChart<Object>(widget.viewModel.chartData,
        defaultInteractions: true,
        animate: false,
        behaviors: [
          
          charts.DomainHighlighter(),

   

          
        ],
               defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
            arcWidth: 60,
            arcRendererDecorators: [new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
              outsideLabelStyleSpec: 
               new charts.TextStyleSpec(
                fontSize: 12,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                color: charts.Color.fromHex(code: "#FFFFFF"),
              ),

            )])
      
        
        ),
```

i want to get like this,
[image]

But instead of this one, i have got this like

[image]

> Blockquote

but i want to make outer boxes values in all fields. how to do that? Is anyone have an idea about it. Please add it

Answer (score 1):

To set outside label, add this property - `new labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.outside` to `charts.ArcLabelDecorator`.

After adding it should look like this,

```
arcRendererDecorators: [new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
              labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.outside),
              outsideLabelStyleSpec: 
               new charts.TextStyleSpec(
                fontSize: 12,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                color: charts.Color.fromHex(code: "#FFFFFF"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
             ),
```

But this will set all labels outside.